# Euler's method, non-existent $y(x)$ function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to approximate the solution to this equation using the Euler's method:

$$y'(x) = 3-\tan(x) \cdot y(x), y(2) = 4$$

When solving for the step of $0.2$, I don't know what to calculate when plugging $y(2.2)$.

What is $y(x)$? Is it the derivative of $3-\tan(x) \cdot y(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

You are solving a special case of the initial value problem
\begin{equation}
u'(x) = f(x,u(x)), \quad u(x_0) = u_0.
\end{equation}
In your case $f$ is defined by $f(x,y) = 3 - \tan(x)y$, you have $x_0 = 2$ and $u_0 = 4$.

When applying Euler's (explicit) method you are attempting to approximate $u(x_0 + nh)$ with $y_n$ where $h > 0$ is your time step, and
\begin{equation}
y_0 = u_0, \quad y_{n+1} = y_n + h f(x_n,y_n).
\end{equation}
In your case, you have $y_0 = 4$, $h = 0.2$, and so
\begin{equation}
y_1 = y_0 + hf(x_0,y_0) = 4 + 0.2 \cdot f(2,4).
\end{equation}